# iterate JSON response in Angular project to create new $scope obj i can use in the app

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

JSON:

```
[{
    "SHFUserID": "400",
    "Status": "2",
    "Ticker": "DPAX",
    "TickerID": "4512",
    "TotalBought": "6300.000000",
    "TotalSold": "4200.000000",
    "TotalSharesNow": "23500.000000"
},
{
    "SHFUserID": "400",
    "Status": null,
    "Ticker": "DPAX",
    "TickerID": "4512",
    "TotalBought": "70500.000000",
    "TotalSold": "47000.000000",
    "TotalSharesNow": "45000.000000"
},
{
    "SHFUserID": "400",
    "Status": null,
    "Ticker": "ONP",        
    "TickerID": "10190",
    "TotalBought": "1175.000000",
    "TotalSold": "1645.000000",
    "TotalSharesNow": "-470.000000"
}]
```

I am trying to iterate over the Json to create a new obj that only contains unique TickerID BUT still populates the "Pending" or "Settled" value if the record Status is a 1 or 2 respectively.

new desired object {"ticker": "Ticker", "tickerId": "TickerID", "Pending": 0 or 1, "Settled": 0 or 1}

expected result based on example data: {"ticker": "DPAX", "tickerId": 4512, "Pending":0, "Settled": 1},{"ticker": "ONP", "tickerId": 10190, "Pending":0, "Settled": 0}

the javascript code is in a controller.js file in an angular project. No matter what code i use to iterate over the existing JSON I get an empty array returned. I've tried a for loop, for in loop and when I run a simple ticker.length function on the existing JSON it returns 0??

controller.js:

```
function TickerListCtrl($scope, Ticker) {

var ticker = [];

ticker = Ticker.query();

$scope.tickers = ticker;

$scope.tickerMenu = ticker.length;  

...
}
```

resource.js

```
angular.module('tickerServices', ['ngResource']).
  factory('Ticker', function($resource){
    return $resource('http:........../Rest/tickers.php', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{UserID:400}, isArray:true}
  });
});
```

app.js

```
 angular.module('tickercat', ['tickercatFilters', 'tickerServices']).
 config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.

  when('/tickers', {templateUrl: 'partials/tickers-list.html',   controller: TickerListCtrl}).

  otherwise({redirectTo: '/tickers'});
}]);
```

tickers-list.html:

```
...
    <div class="span3">
  <!--Sidebar content-->

  ...

  <ul class="tickerList">
    <li ng-repeat="ticker in tickers | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
      <a href="#/ticker/{{ticker.TickerID}}">{{ticker.Ticker}}</a>
      <p>{{ticker.Status}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
{{tickerMenu}}
</div>
```

the browser outputs the "tickerList" as expected but the {{tickerMenu}} returns 0. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Does Ticker.query() make an AJAX request?

Comment: it is a REST call that returns the JSON as it appears in the post

Comment: Then you have to assign tickerMenu when that request returns. An AJAX call is not a blocking call, your code goes on by assigning tickerMenu before tickers is populated.

Comment: i am not sure i follow. how could $scope.tickers populate correctly but $scope.tickerMenu doesn't? they both rely on the ticker obj.

Comment: Can you post Ticker.query() implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was to create a custom .filter.

so: ticker in tickers | myCustomFilter

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters

Answer (score 0):

Is it not because you have the controller against the UL element but call the tickerMenu scope attribute after the closing UL?

Comment: i am using a partial to make the both $scope elements available to the entire HTML partial

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about partial usage and scope but I created a little fiddle to show what I meant with regards to the controller scope.  I'm very new to Angular so hopefully I'm not trying to teach you how to suck lemons.  In the example you can see that I placed the controller on the containing div.

http://jsfiddle.net/stevendwebster/DLjvE/

Comment: the fiddle works but I am loading the scope via a partial. i updated the post to reflect the app.js